# Accessing Plist From Sqlite Database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, plist

My target is to populate an Tableview. For that m using Sqlite database as I need to add, delete and update that table using array. Using Sqlite, I can easily achieve this target. But,once we restart our app all the data stored in that array would be lost. But, the data that the table has, should be available in all the devices in which this app has be installed.  To achieve this target I think of using Plist. Is there any other way to achieve this target?

Comment: forgive me if i m wrong but do u want to access plist rather then Sqlite because ur Title suggested that u want to access plist from Sqlite

Comment: Why you wanna go for plist? You have all the data in DB, you can make use of it, right!!

Comment: yes u r right..but what would be the way to achieve the goal.

Comment: @Nina : Once u delete ur app then u have to recreate all the objects but I don’t want that..

Comment: Even if you use plist, you should recreate them :-)

Comment: I believe we can't have data stored if the app is deleted :-) And it is pointless to have the data when the app is not there!!

Comment: Yup Nina, u r r8.. I need to put sqlite database in document directory, then every thing will be OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't worded very clearly but from what I understand, you have some static data you've inserted into a sqlite database. If you want this data to be available, you should take the sqlite database containing that data and keep it in your app's `Resources` folder so that it actually gets copied to the app. You can then acquire a path to the database file using `NSBundle` methods and go from there.

If it's not a lot of data, you can just create a static array or something and store it there. You might also consider looking into Core Data instead of working with raw sqlite.

You could also store the data in a property list or some other file and read it out of there. Don't use `NSUserDefaults` for this though; that property list is more appropriate for user preferences, not static data.